# Dúvida sobre Remoção em Listas Duplamente Encadeadas(C/ Inserção Ordenada)

Tags: c++, lista, struct, lista-encadeada

Em uma aula de C++ o professor havia proposto uma atividade onde eu tinha que fazer um programa no formato de uma lista duplamente encadeada com inserção ordenada. No entanto, estou com um problema na parte da Remoção. **Ao remover todos os membros a partir de qualquer uma das extremidades até a outra(do inicio até fim ou vice versa) o programa "chasha" quando removo o último membro da lista**.

Gostaria de saber qual a razão do problema, acredito que esteja na programação do ant/prox uma vez que chega uma hora em que o inicio é igual ao fim.

Todas as outras funções do programa funcionam, só falta corrigir este detalhe na remoção.
Segue abaixo a estrutura base, a função remover e a sub-função "localizar_busca" que ela utiliza.

```
typedef struct aula{
aula *prox;
aula *ant;
int x;
};

aula *localizar_busca(aula *w, int v){
while (w!=NULL && w->x!=v){
    w=w->prox;
}
if(w == NULL)
    return NULL;
else
    return w;
}


void listar(aula **inicio){
aula *x_aux;
int contador=0;
if(*inicio == NULL){
    printf("\n");
    printf("Fila vazia...");
}
else{
    printf("\n");
    x_aux = *inicio;
    do{
        printf("Elemento %d da fila = %d\n", contador, (x_aux)->x);
        contador+=1;
        x_aux = x_aux->prox;
    }
    while(x_aux!= NULL);
}
}


void remover(aula **inicio, aula **fim){
int aux, contador = 0;
aula *enc;
if(*inicio == NULL){
    printf("\nLista vazia, nao ha elementos a serem removidos.");
}
else{
    printf("\nLista atual: \n");
    listar(&*inicio);
    printf("\n\nEscolha um elemento listado a ser removido: ");
    scanf("%d", &aux);
    enc = localizar_busca(*inicio, aux);
    if(enc == NULL){
        printf("\nElemento nao encontrado.");
    }
    else if(aux == (*inicio)->x){
        printf("\n%d removido com sucesso!", (*inicio)->x);
        (*inicio) = (*inicio)->prox;
        (*inicio)->ant = NULL;
    }
    else if(aux == (*fim)->x){
        printf("\n%d removido com sucesso!", (*fim)->x);
        (*fim) = (*fim)->ant;
        (*fim)->prox = NULL;
    }
    else{
        printf("\n%d removido com sucesso!", enc->x);
        enc->ant->prox = enc->prox;
        enc->prox->ant = enc->ant;
        free(enc);
    }
}
}
```

Eis o main:

```
int main(){
aula *novo, *aux, *inicio = NULL, *fim = NULL;
char OP;

do{
    printf("\nEscolha o que deseja fazer: \n1 - Inserir\n2 - Listar\n3 - Buscar\n4 - Remover\n5 - Esvaziar\n6 - Sair\n");
    OP = getche();

    switch(OP){
    case '1':
        inserir(&inicio, &fim);
        break;
    case '2':
        listar(&inicio);
        break;
    case '3':
        buscar_lista(&inicio, &fim);
        break;
    case '4':
        remover(&inicio, &fim);
        break;
    case '5':
        esvaziar(&inicio, &fim);
        break;
    case '6':
        esvaziar(&inicio, &fim);
        break;
    default:
        printf("\nOP invalido");
        break;
    }
    }while(OP!='6');
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quando analisamos o que acontece se passamos uma lista com um único nó, o problema fica óbvio:

Só pra relembrar: quando a lista tem um só nó, `**inicio == **fim` e `(*inicio)->prox == (*inicio)->ant == (*fim)->prox == (*fim)->ant == NULL`.

```
void remover(aula **inicio, aula **fim) {
    int aux, contador = 0;
    aula *enc;
```

Você começa verificando se a lista não contém nós, isto é, se `*inicio` é vazia. Neste caso, não é.

```
    if(*inicio == NULL) {
        printf("\nLista vazia, nao ha elementos a serem removidos.");
    }
    else {
```

Como não é, mostramos a lista atual e pedimos qual item deve ser removido:

```
        printf("\nLista atual: \n");
        listar(&*inicio);
        printf("\n\nEscolha um elemento listado a ser removido: ");
        scanf("%d", &aux);
```

O usuário supostamente escolhe o último nó que restou, e então fazemos uma busca linear para encontrar o nó solicitado: Se não encontrar, reclamamos.

```
        enc = localizar_busca(*inicio, aux);
        if(enc == NULL){
            printf("\nElemento nao encontrado.");
        }
```

Tendo encontrado, testamos o primeiro caso, em que o valor solicitado é `(*inicio)->x`.

Como é, entramos no `if`:

```
        else if(aux == (*inicio)->x){
            printf("\n%d removido com sucesso!", (*inicio)->x);
```

Primeiro, reportamos sucesso um pouco prematuramente.

```
            (*inicio) = (*inicio)->prox;
```

Depois, fazemos `inicio` apontar para o sucessor do nó inicial, `(*inicio)->prox`, que como vimos acima, é `NULL`.

```
            (*inicio)->ant = NULL;
```

Finalmente, fazemos com que o nó predecessor deste sucessor seja `NULL`, para que removamos a menção ao nó por apagar da lista.

Mas, `(*inicio)` já é `NULL`!  Assim, estamos tentando escrever numa posição de memória inválida (já que não se pode desreferenciar um ponteiro nulo). Resultado? Segfault.

Abaixo, continuam os outros casos, nos quais não entraremos porque estão no `else`. Mas note que somente no último caso que o `free(enc) é executado, de forma que todas as vezes que removemos um nó do princípio ou do fim da lista,`sizeof(aula)` bytes vazam...

```
        }
        else if(aux == (*fim)->x){
            printf("\n%d removido com sucesso!", (*fim)->x);
            (*fim) = (*fim)->ant;
            (*fim)->prox = NULL;
        }
        else{
            printf("\n%d removido com sucesso!", enc->x);
            enc->ant->prox = enc->prox;
            enc->prox->ant = enc->ant;
            free(enc);
        }
    }
}
```

A minha recomendação, portanto, é incluir um caso testando *explicitamente* por `enc == *inicio == *fim`, em que só se setaria `*inicio = *fim = NULL` e se daria o `free()` no nó restante. Finalmente, é melhor reportar sucesso só depois de efetuar todas as outras operações: é mais correto.

Comment: Não havia pensado nisso. Obrigado pela solução(mesmo sendo simples aplicação de lógica)! Aliás, minha justificativa pro print prematuro era que eu só queria mostrar ao usuário o elemento que o mesmo optou por remover.